# Difference between local and temporal variables in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to know the following:
Do the terms 'local variable' and 'temporary variable' refer to the same thing in C++?

Comment: there is also "temporary object" which is unrelated to these concepts

Comment: oh actually this was what i was looking for!
So I guess I'll be fine just looking up what local objects are... Thank you very much Bryan. 
Since Greg answered the question I originaly asked I guess I'll have to mark his answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I discovered an article about "temporary object"
http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=198

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never heard the term "temporal variable", so I'm going to assume you mean "[temporary variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_variable)".

No, they are not necessarily the same thing.

A temporary variable is something that holds a useful value for just a short time (say, when you are swapping the values of two variables). A temporary variable can be a local variable or a global variable.

The term *local variable* refers to storage location and scope; the term *temporary variable* refers to the purpose for which a variable is used.